# Forcings that preserve $\mathtt{PSP}$

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, descriptive-set-theory

By $\mathtt{PSP}$ I mean the statement "every subset of the reals has the perfect set property, i.e. either is countable or it contains an homeomorphic copy of the Cantor space $2^\omega$".
I was wandering what forcing notions preserve such a statement:

- Are there some known properties $P$ of forcing notions such that if $\mathbb{P}$ satisfies $P$ then $V \vDash \mathtt{PSP} \Rightarrow V[G] \vDash \mathtt{PSP}$ for any $G$ $\mathbb{P}$-generic?
- What are known forcings that have such a property?

Thanks!

Comment: Forcings that do not add sets of reals, for example. :P

Comment: This may not be what you are looking for, but Section 12.1 of Geometric Set Theory covers partial orders in the Solovay model whose forcing extensions satisfy the Silver dichotomy for Borel equivalence relations, which is a generalization of the perfect set property.